# per file compile optimisation settings

Tags: hardhat, solc, foundry, optimization

I use both hardhat and foundry to build and both seem to offer just one value for runs for the whole project. But I have one large initialisation contract which will only be run once so I'd like runs = 1 for that, but say 10000 everywhere else. Is there a way to specify runs=1 just for the large init contract that sets everything up?